# Does the quantum Jensen-Shannon divergence appear in any quantum algorithms or texts on quantum computing?

Tags: resource-request, density-matrix, entropy, information-theory, cq-states

The generalization of probability distributions on **density matrices** allows to define [quantum Jensen–Shannon divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence#Quantum_Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence) (QJSD), which uses von Neumann entropy. Does QJSD appear in any quantum algorithms or texts on quantum computing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That quantity appears to be identical to Holevo information, which turns out to be the upper bound on how much classical information you can transmit using a quantum channel [1].

More generally the Holevo information is an upper bound for a quantity called "accessible information" which is (roughly speaking) the maximum information you can learn from an optimal measurement performed on an ensemble of quantum states.

---

[1] Holevo, A. S. (1973). Bounds for the quantity of information transmitted by a quantum communication channel. Problemy Peredachi Informatsii, 9(3), 3-11.

Comment: what is the classical analogue of Holevo information?

Comment: It looks/behaves _like_ a mutual information defined between the classical and quantum parts of an ensemble. If I "tag" each member of a quantum ensemble with a classical bit of information - $\rho = \sum_i p_i |i \rangle \langle i |_C \otimes \rho_{i, Q}$ I can write the joint entropy of this classical-quantum system as $H(C, Q) = H(C) + \sum_i p_i S(\rho_{i, Q})$, the first term being entropy over classical distribution $(p_i, |i\rangle \langle i|)$. Then define $\chi$ as $S(C:Q) \equiv H(C) + S(\rho) - H(C, Q)$ to recover Holevo information.

Comment: but its more intuitive to think of $\chi$ as the upper bound to accessible information, which really is just mutual information between an (optimal) measurement and the input state $\rho$.